# Django textfield capacity?

Tags: django, django-models

What is the capacity of a `TextField` in Django?  The only reference in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield) states that a `TextField` is

```
A large text field.  The default form widget for this field is a TextArea
```

This is a spectacularly vague and unusable piece of documentation.

Comment: It depends on the database you're using.

Comment: The reason it is "vague" is because It depends on the backend database. For example, if mysql is being used, it evaluates to :  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html and so on for various databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer that the Django devs already provided!

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8263

TL;DR: There is no limit